# Nested List comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a List inside of a List in Python and i want to convert them into a single list using List comprehension:

```
>>> aa = [[1,2],[1,2]]
>>> bb = [num for num in numbers for numbers in aa]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined
>>>
```

What am i doing wrong?

***The answer to my question isn't on the duplicate as stated above, it is below this question.**

Comment: `for numbers in aa` part should come first.

Comment: Haha. woah! that was quick. Thank you! @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested For Loops Using List Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633140/nested-for-loops-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: [One more link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927553/list-comprehension-in-nested-lists)

Comment: ya same question, but did u see the same answer on those questions that solved my problem? @khajvah

Comment: btw, `itertools.chain(*aa)` does the same thing and is a lot more concise.

Comment: alright. thanks, i will try that too. @EliKorvigo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the `for` loops in your list comprehension in the opposite order -

```
bb = [num for numbers in aa for num in numbers]
```

Demo -

```
>>> aa = [[1,2],[1,2]]
>>> bb = [num for numbers in aa for num in numbers]
>>> bb
[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: yes, yes. Thank you. that was confusing. I thought that i had it in the correct order. :)

Comment: python list comprehensions *are* confusing. unfortunately there is no decent alternative in the language.